# Flutter Just Audio Background not playing audio when navigating to other screen

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart, just-audio

I am using just audio background package to play audio in the background. As you can see I am using the example code available on pub dev as I have just modified it.

> The problem is that the audio in the background stops when I navigate to another screen. Also, the notification disappears. I tried to removed the _player.dispose(); method which is an instance of AudioPlayer and then it worked but now the audio is not changing when i tap on another song.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:just_audio_background/just_audio_background.dart';
import 'package:uri_to_file/uri_to_file.dart';
import 'package:video_downloader/utils/common.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

        String songURIString = "";
        int? songDurationValue = 0;
        String songTitleString = "";

        class AudioPlayer3 extends StatefulWidget {
          var songDurationSec, songTitleString, songUriString, albumTitle;
          AudioPlayer3(
              {Key? key,
              this.songDurationSec,
              this.songUriString,
              this.songTitleString,
              this.albumTitle})
              : super(key: key);

          @override
          AudioPlayer3State createState() => AudioPlayer3State();
        }

        class AudioPlayer3State extends State<AudioPlayer3> {
          static int _nextMediaId = 0;
          late AudioPlayer _player;
          late final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [
            AudioSource.uri(
              Uri.parse("${widget.songUriString}"),
              tag: MediaItem(
                id: '${widget.songUriString}',
                album: "${widget.albumTitle}",
                title: "${widget.songTitleString}",
                artUri: Uri.parse("https://www.linkpicture.com/q/music-note.png"),
              ),
            ),
          ]);
          int _addedCount = 0;

          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            _player = AudioPlayer();

            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
              _init();
              setArtUri();
              setAudioValues();
            });
          }

          Future<void> initNotification() async {
            await JustAudioBackground.init(
              androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.ryanheise.bg_demo.channel.audio',
              androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio playback',
              androidNotificationOngoing: true,
            );
          }

          Future<void> _init() async {
            final session = await AudioSession.instance;
            await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration.speech());
            // Listen to errors during playback.
            _player.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {},
                onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
              print('A stream error occurred: $e');
            });
            try {
              await _player.setAudioSource(_playlist);
            } catch (e, stackTrace) {
              // Catch load errors: 404, invalid url ...
              print("Error loading playlist: $e");
              print(stackTrace);
            }
          }

          Future<void> setAudioValues() async {
            setState(() {
              songTitleString = widget.songTitleString;
              songURIString = widget.songUriString;
              songDurationValue = widget.songDurationSec;
              print('Song name is ' + songTitleString);
            });
          }

          Future<void> setArtUri() async {
            File file = await toFile(''); // Converting uri to file
          }

          @override
          void dispose() {
            _player.dispose();
            super.dispose();
          }

          Stream<PositionData> get _positionDataStream =>
              Rx.combineLatest3<Duration, Duration, Duration?, PositionData>(
                  _player.positionStream,
                  _player.bufferedPositionStream,
                  _player.durationStream,
                  (position, bufferedPosition, duration) => PositionData(
                      position, bufferedPosition, duration ?? Duration.zero));

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              home: Scaffold(
                body: SafeArea(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: StreamBuilder<SequenceState?>(
                          stream: _player.sequenceStateStream,
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            final state = snapshot.data;
                            if (state?.sequence.isEmpty ?? true) {
                              return const SizedBox();
                            }
                            final metadata = state!.currentSource!.tag as MediaItem;
                            return Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Center(
                                        child:
                                            Image.network(metadata.artUri.toString())),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(metadata.album!,
                                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
                                Text(metadata.title),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      ControlButtons(_player),
                      StreamBuilder<PositionData>(
                        stream: _positionDataStream,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          final positionData = snapshot.data;
                          return SeekBar(
                            duration: positionData?.duration ?? Duration.zero,
                            position: positionData?.position ?? Duration.zero,
                            bufferedPosition:
                                positionData?.bufferedPosition ?? Duration.zero,
                            onChangeEnd: (newPosition) {
                              _player.seek(newPosition);
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          StreamBuilder<LoopMode>(
                            stream: _player.loopModeStream,
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              final loopMode = snapshot.data ?? LoopMode.off;
                              const icons = [
                                Icon(Icons.repeat, color: Colors.grey),
                                // Icon(Icons.repeat, color: Colors.orange),
                                Icon(Icons.repeat_one, color: Colors.orange),
                              ];
                              const cycleModes = [
                                LoopMode.off,
                                // LoopMode.all,
                                LoopMode.one,
                              ];
                              final index = cycleModes.indexOf(loopMode);
                              return IconButton(
                                icon: icons[index],
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _player.setLoopMode(cycleModes[
                                      (cycleModes.indexOf(loopMode) + 1) %
                                          cycleModes.length]);
                                },
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              "Now Playing",
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 240.0,
                        child: StreamBuilder<SequenceState?>(
                          stream: _player.sequenceStateStream,
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            final state = snapshot.data;
                            final sequence = state?.sequence ?? [];
                            return ReorderableListView(
                              onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                                if (oldIndex < newIndex) newIndex--;
                                _playlist.move(oldIndex, newIndex);
                              },
                              children: [
                                for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++)
                                  Dismissible(
                                    key: ValueKey(sequence[i]),
                                    background: Container(
                                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                      child: const Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                                        child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    onDismissed: (dismissDirection) {
                                      _playlist.removeAt(i);
                                    },
                                    child: Material(
                                      color: i == state!.currentIndex
                                          ? Colors.grey.shade300
                                          : null,
                                      child: ListTile(
                                        title: Text(sequence[i].tag.title as String),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          _player.seek(Duration.zero, index: i);
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }

        class ControlButtons extends StatelessWidget {
          final AudioPlayer player;

          const ControlButtons(this.player, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.volume_up),
                  onPressed: () {
                    showSliderDialog(
                      context: context,
                      title: "Adjust volume",
                      divisions: 10,
                      min: 0.0,
                      max: 1.0,
                      stream: player.volumeStream,
                      onChanged: player.setVolume,
                      value: 5,
                    );
                  },
                ),
                StreamBuilder<PlayerState>(
                  stream: player.playerStateStream,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    final playerState = snapshot.data;
                    final processingState = playerState?.processingState;
                    final playing = playerState?.playing;
                    if (processingState == ProcessingState.loading ||
                        processingState == ProcessingState.buffering) {
                      return Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        width: 64.0,
                        height: 64.0,
                        child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    } else if (playing != true) {
                      return IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                        iconSize: 64.0,
                        onPressed: player.play,
                      );
                    } else if (processingState != ProcessingState.completed) {
                      return IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.pause),
                        iconSize: 64.0,
                        onPressed: player.pause,
                      );
                    } else {
                      return IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.replay),
                        iconSize: 64.0,
                        onPressed: () => player.seek(Duration.zero,
                            index: player.effectiveIndices!.first),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
                StreamBuilder<double>(
                  stream: player.speedStream,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) => IconButton(
                    icon: Text("${snapshot.data?.toStringAsFixed(1)}x",
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      showSliderDialog(
                        context: context,
                        title: "Adjust speed",
                        divisions: 10,
                        min: 0.5,
                        max: 1.5,
                        stream: player.speedStream,
                        onChanged: player.setSpeed,
                        value: 5,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution to this issue. The problem was that i was initiating the audio player instance twice. I had to make only one instance on the landing screen and share the same instance across all the screens.

Pass this instance across all the screens.

```
AudioPlayer _player = AudioPlayer();
```